# MS Access Update Query to SharePoint List Locking up, no errors

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010, vba

I am combining multiple Excel Worksheets into one SharePoint list so our data is all in one place and modifiable by multiple users at once.  The Append query worked without a hitch.

Now I am trying to update one filed in the list with an update query but it keeps locking up MS Access (Not Responding, 100% CPU usage). I have to terminate from the task manager.

I have let it run for as much as 10 minutes. So then I switched to the one time use sub procedure below to update through a recordset. Same issue.

I am able to update the field manually one at a time via the linked list in MS Access. I can update the field via datasheet and dialog in SharePoint.

**SharePoint 2010** 
**MS Access 2013**

Does anyone have any ideas?

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateDataPlateDates()

On Error GoTo err_trap
    Dim db As DAO.Database: Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer: i = 1
    Dim vDate As Variant
    Dim sNum As String

    strSQL = "SELECT TML.[SERIAL NUMBER], TML.[DATA PLATE DATE] FROM [Tool Master List] AS TML WHERE (((TML.[DATA PLATE DATE]) Is Null));"

    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveLast: .MoveFirst
            Do Until .EOF
                sNum = ![SERIAL NUMBER].Value
                vDate = DLookup("[ACCEPT DATE]", "Tool information", "[SERIAL NUMBER]='" & sNum & "'")
                Debug.Print i, sNum, vDate
                If Not (IsNull(vDate) Or IsEmpty(vDate)) Then
                    vDate = CDate(vDate)

                    .Edit

                        ![DATA Plate Date] = vDate  '//FAILS-LOCKS UP RIGHT HERE WITHOUT and ERROR
                    .Update
                End If

                .MoveNext

                i = i + 1

                sNum = vbNullString
                vDate = Null
                DoEvents
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
exit_sub:
    Exit Sub
err_trap:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Stop
    Resume


End Sub
```

Comment: I should have added that there are NO Workflows running against the SharePoint list.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the item you are trying to update is being edited by a user? Have you considered linking the SharePoint table and performing an update query instead?

Comment: I did and update query first but it kept timing out without updating. So I switched to the recordset method to see if I could figure out where it was hanging up. There is no indication of what is doing it. I finally deleted all the records and reappended them with all of the required data. This is not something I want to keep doing though.

Comment: Try stepping through field by field with your update. It might be a data type issue. Also limit your update to one record.